# I've got a issue related with align, inline-block, picture, and font

Tags: html, css, overflow, inline, display

[image]

Please check the image above, the 3,4th pictures slightly spill out. and I think it is because of h4, when the browser is reduced, it overflowed and make next line. I want to align that evenly. How can i solve this?

```css
.items {
  width: 23.2%;
  margin-right: 1.2%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.items:nth-child(5n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.items span:first-child {
  position: absolute;
}

.items h4 {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.items img {
  width: 100%;
}

.items img.star {
  width: auto;
}

.items span:last-child {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

```html
<article class="shop_best">
  <div class="line_sec">
    <span></span>
    <h3>베스트셀러</h3><span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <span><img src="images/best_sell1_2.png"></span>
    <img src="images/best_sell1.jpg">
    <h4>메모리즈 바디오일 – 100ml</h4>
    <img src="images/rate_5.png" class="star" alt="rating">
    <span>28,000원<span>
                </div>
                <div class="items">
                    <span><img src="images/best_sell2_2.png"></span>
    <img src="images/best_sell2.jpg">
    <h4>스킨 리파잉 크림 클렌저 – 60ml</h4>
    <img src="images/rate_4.png" class="star" alt="rating">
    <span>54,000원<span>
                </div>
                <div class="items">
                    <span><img src="images/best_sell3_2.png"></span>
    <img src="images/best_sell3.jpg">
    <h4>아로마테라피 시너지 바디오일 – 100ml</h4>
    <img src="images/rate_4.png" class="star" alt="rating">
    <span>29,000원<span>
                </div>
                <div class="items">
                    <span><img src="images/best_sell4_2.png"></span>
    <img src="images/best_sell4.jpg">
    <h4>인블룸 그린 버베나 프레이그런스 디퓨저 – 300ml</h4>
    <img src="images/rate_5.png" class="star" alt="rating">
    <span>42,000원<span>
                </div>
```

Comment: Your text is on 2 lines for the pictures 3 and 4 and that is why they are not aligned. On the second set of pictures the text is also on 2 lines and that is why the show OK. So it's up to you to decide. I would set a fixed height for the text are so always to have room for the text to show on 2 lines.

Comment: all you need is vertical-align:top to your elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, the most flexible solution was to use a jQuery based adjustment. If you always have the same content, you can certainly work with orientations in CSS. But if the content is different or is dynamically updated, I recommend the following method.

**In your html file**

At first, you have to pack all headline elements in a container and give them the same class name.

```
<div class="headline">
<h4> My Headline </h4>
</div>
```

**In your jQuery file**

This function checks every element with same class, searches for the element, which has the heighest space (i.e. if a linebreak was necessary) and set all the elements to this height. So all headlines get the same space.

```
function equal_height() {
  var highest_element = 0;

  // Lösche die Höhe
  $('.headline').each(function() {
    $(this).removeAttr('style');
  });

  // Prüfe, welches Element am höchsten ist
  $('.headline').each(function() {
    if ($(this).height() > highest_element) {
      highest_element = $(this).height();
    }
  });

  // Weise diese Höhe allen Elementen zu.
  $('.headline').each(function() {
    $(this).height(highest_element);
  });
};

/*Load Function after all CSS loaded*/
$(window).on('load',function(){
   equal_height();
});

/*Fire Function when Resizing*/
var resizeTimer;
$(window).on('load', function() {
  clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
  resizeTimer = setTimeout(equal_height, 100);
});
```

For me, it works perfectly with dynamic content. All the headline are set to equal space, based on the element with the most space. After that, centering should be quiet easy with css.

I hope it helped. Of course I can answer questions.

PS: You can view the same principle on my website https://www.baumarktaktion.de.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your items in 1 `div` and add following css to the `div`

```css
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
```

Like so :

```html
<div style="display: flex;flex-wrap: wrap;">
  <div class="items">..</div>
  <div class="items">..</div>
  <div class="items">..</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the length of the product name, your boxes are pulled up. It will be logical to wrap all your boxes in a separate div, since your article with boxes has one parent. Set the `flex` rule to the box parent `items_box`.

```css
.items { width: 23.2%;  margin-right: 1.2%; display: inline-block; position: relative; }
.items:nth-child(5n) {margin-right: 0;}
.items span:first-child {position: absolute;} 
.items h4 {font-size: 0.9em; width: 100%; padding: 10px 0 0 0 ;}
.items img{width: 100%;}
.items img.star {width: auto;}
.items span:last-child {display: block; font-size: 0.8em;}

/*add this it*/

.items_box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}
```

```html
<article class="shop_best">
            <div class="line_sec">
                <span></span><h3>베스트셀러</h3><span></span>
            </div>
           <div class="items_box">
            <div class="items">
                <span><img src="images/best_sell1_2.png"></span>
                <img src="images/best_sell1.jpg">
                <h4>메모리즈 바디오일 – 100ml</h4>
                <img src="images/rate_5.png" class="star" alt="rating">
                <span>28,000원</span>
            </div>
            <div class="items">
                <span><img src="images/best_sell2_2.png"></span>
                <img src="images/best_sell2.jpg">
                <h4>스킨 리파잉 크림 클렌저 – 60ml</h4>
                <img src="images/rate_4.png" class="star"  alt="rating">
                <span>54,000원</span>
            </div>
            <div class="items">
                <span><img src="images/best_sell3_2.png"></span>
                <img src="images/best_sell3.jpg">
                <h4>아로마테라피 시너지 바디오일 – 100ml</h4>
                <img src="images/rate_4.png" class="star"  alt="rating">
                <span>29,000원</span>
            </div>
            <div class="items">
                <span><img src="images/best_sell4_2.png"></span>
                <img src="images/best_sell4.jpg">
                <h4>인블룸 그린 버베나 프레이그런스 디퓨저 – 300ml</h4>
                <img src="images/rate_5.png" class="star"  alt="rating">
                <span>42,000원</span>
            </div>
          </div>
</article>
```